Sometimes Redlock lock Key gets acquired by multiple instances at same time
in Nestjs, I have this cron job that I want to execute it once if multiple instances of the app exists by using Redlock:
    @Cron('*/1 * * * * *')
    async test(): Promise<void> {

        try {
            const lockKey = 'test-cron-job-lock';
            const lock = await this.redisService.acquireLock(lockKey, 1000); // 1 second
            this.logger.log(`Cron job at ${this.getTimeWithoutMilliseconds()}`);

            await this.redisService.releaseLock(lock);
        } catch (e) {
            this.logger.error('Error in test cron job');
        }
    }

it works, but sometimes the lockKey gets acquired by multiple instances at same time.
App A:
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:48 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:48Z
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:49 PM   ERROR Error in test cron job
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:50 PM   ERROR Error in test cron job
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:51 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:51Z
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:52 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:52Z
[Nest] 8872  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:53 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:53Z

App B:
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:48 PM   ERROR Error in test cron job
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:49 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:49Z
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:50 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:50Z
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:51 PM   ERROR Error in test cron job
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:52 PM   ERROR Error in test cron job
[Nest] 8886  - 10/04/2024, 4:06:53 PM     LOG Cron job at 2024-10-04T13:06:53Z

As you can see both instances run the job at 2024-10-04T13:06:53Z. why?

Can you share details on your redis server? One standalone node or a cluster/sharded?

@avifen one node. I am suspecting that this is happening because both of them trying to acquire the lock at same time ( < 50ms apart )

I'll give an answer.

And take a look on ValKey-Glide, you'll get the best support possible, it's a promise :)

Generally race condition with Redlock is rare, but since you set the cron exactly at the same time and the lock TTL is pretty short, a race once in a while is possible.
There are few ways to solve it, with pros and cons -

longer acquire TTL, not perfect but reduce the chances of a race.
Jitter — add a random delay. Make sure that the delay is not longer than the TTL, otherwise you'll get double action.
Use SET with NX and EX with TTL as parameters after acquiring, something like SET "running" NX EX 10 — if the key already set, you'll get null, otherwise you'll get OK, this is atomic operation so it's not possible to have a race, but in this case I would leave the lock and use the set alone. The EX make sure that the key release after a while.

Generally I would say that the Redlock fits for cases when you can't predict behavior, and you want to make sure that always there's just one client having it.
But if they all start at the same time, taking about the same time to perform, and you need something fully atomic, I'd use SET key NX EX sec with a slight jitter and you are pretty bullet prof.

Great. Atomic SET solved it for me.. but, if we used a cluster in the future, redlock will not work in cron jobs. Maybe it was not built for these kind of a use-case!?
Thanks for your time and answer.

If the key is the same key, it goes to the same shard (node), so it will solve your issue also with cluster. Keys are distributed base on a hash to a slot, meaning all the cluster will read the same key from the same slots. I need to check internal implementation, but I hardly believe there's an option that a replica will approve write with NX without checking with master and keeping the "atomic" behavior. There's a lot of work done to not break standalone promises with cluster mode, since cluster mode is recommended by the ValKey (or Redis) dev community.

Oh, you talked about redlock -  as said, if the case is not random usage of lock, use SET NX EX, it's better for deterministic results.

Thank you for clarifying. I will definitely dig deeper on this!
